# AX2009 AIF web services not success using SoapUi

Tags: iis, soap, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

I am getting an error trying to connect a AX web service using SoapUi. In IIS web server this specific web service is successfully browsed. On the web.config file I am using not windows authentication but wsHttpBinding binding.
I followed up so many suggestions that I have seen googling, but this web service fails yet.
I really appreciate new clues from AIF experts to fix it. It's a really nightmare so far.
Thanks!
Pep

```
s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <s:Code>
            <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
            <s:Subcode>
               <s:Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">a:BadContextToken</s:Value>
            </s:Subcode>
         </s:Code>
         <s:Reason>
            <s:Text xml:lang="en-GB">The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services/specific service operation' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.</s:Text>
         </s:Reason>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am completely taking a shot in the dark from vaguely remembering something from AX09, but check your app pools in IIS under their advanced settings and toggle a mix of the `Enable 32-Bit Applications` and/or `Managed Pipeline Mode`. Try adjusting the timeout longer too?

Comment: Hi Alex K. Thanks for your message. I have checked your suggestions and I set up accordingly, but still prompting the same error.